# UIImage image is alway nill

Tags: uiimage

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if(imageView1.image == nil){
        imageView1.image = image;
    }
    else if(imageView2.image == nil){
        imageView2.image = image;
    }
    else if(imageView3.image == nil){
        imageView3.image = image;
    }

    //pickedImage = TRUE;
}
```

I have this code and it never go to the second "if else" statement.
Although it assigns the image to imageView1, next time the imageView1.image is still null. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you connected all IBOutlets in the NIB? It’s what I usually miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions now.

1.Try this

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

use "**valueForKey**" instead of **objectForKey**

> **2**.  You have to dismiss and release the UIImagePickerController before you try to do anything with the info dictionary. To be super-clear:
>
> **This WILL NOT WORK:**
>
> ```
> - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
>                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {    
>
>   myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
>
>
>   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
>   [picker release];
> }
> ```
>
> **THIS WILL WORK**
>
> ```
> - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
>                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
>
>   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
>   [picker release];
>
>
>   myUIImageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
>
>         if(imageView1.image == nil){
>             imageView1.image = image;
>         }
>         else if(imageView2.image == nil){
>           imageView2.image = image;
>         }
>        else if(imageView3.image == nil){
>         imageView3.image = image;
>       }             
> }
> ```

Comment: [picker release]; what if the class is in arc?

Comment: i am not getting "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" parameter in info dictionary for iphone5.this happens only for some images..for other images it works fine.